# R how to conditionally update a numeric value in a data frame

Tags: r

I am trying to update a value in a data frame that is numeric when it is above a certain value due to input error.  The value should be in the hundreds but, on occasion is in the thousands as it has an extra zero.
Data Frame is called df and the column is called Value1

```
Value1 (sample values)
650
6640
550
```

The value for 7650 should be 765.  I am trying to use the following:

```
df$Value1[df$Value1>1000] <- df$Value1/10
```

This is generating very odd results.  I end up not having values greater than 1000 but, a value of 6640 became 74.1 instead of 664 as I expected.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to subset your RHS too `df$Value1[df$Value1>1000] <- df$Value1[df$Value1>1000] /10` OR just use `ifelse`

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do this in one line, without having to compute the target row indexes twice:

```
df$Value1[ris <- which(df$Value1>1000)] <- df$Value1[ris]/10;
df;
##   Value1
## 1    650
## 2    664
## 3    550
```

**Data**

```
df <- data.frame(Value1=c(650L,6640L,550L));
```

Answer (score 1):

Or we can use `data.table` (data from @bgoldst's post)

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[Value1 > 1000, Value1 := Value1/10]
df
#   Value1
#1:    650
#2:    664
#3:    550
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way :

```
 #Sample data frame
 d1
  Value1
1    650
2   6640
3    550

d1$Value1 = as.numeric(substr(d1$Value1,1,3))

#result
d1
  Value1
1    650
2    664
3    550
```